# How to open the application by just the URL in adress bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a application. Need to redirect address, and that address should open my Application.

So in generall - I want to open my Application when someone visit a properly URL link in Android browser.

I have created a `App Links` in my Android Application using `App Links Assistant`. So I added a proper intent filters like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:path="/app" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then added some logic to reload my application when user visit a site. I associated my app with my website with `Digital Asset Links JSON` file. I have tested it and everything works fine in Assistant Manager.

So.. I entered the address into the browser and only the page started.

Added to `index.html` some `<a href="">` links to test it.

```
<a href="http://example.com/app">HTTP</a><Br>
<a href="https://example.com/app">HTTPS.</a><br>
<a href="app://example.com/app">APP</a><br>
```

> All the above links open the application as intended.

Redirect?
I have added in `META` tag redirect to the same site... Yes, a loop has been created, predictable. Site loading over and over.

`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example.com/app">`

Same situation, without loading page constantly if changed protocol to `app` in redirect `META` tag.

What should I change? Maybe some `JS` script to click that link?

My app using external SSO module that should redirect back to application when user sign in. Right now it opens a external browser when I can register or sign in, and then get a redirect to a site, then I have to close browser to back to application... Maybe there is another sollution for this case than redirecting via another site to back application.
Im also not a developer of SSO module, so cant change behaviour with redirecting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need to redirect address, and that address should open my Application.

That is not generally possible. Few, if any, Android Web browsers will honor app links for anything other than ordinary hyperlinks.

Note, of course, that there is no requirement for a Web browser to support app links at all, and there are *many* Web browsers for Android.

> What should I change?

Change your expectations.

Comment: Oh, I see... probably for security reasons. It makes sense, but in this case I would really need it to work... However, if it is impossible, it happens :/

My app need to use external SSO module that should redirect to application. Right now it opens a external browser when I can register or sign in, and then get a redirect to a site, that I have to close to back to application... Maybe there is another sollution then for this case than redirecting via another site to application.